# Expectation of nonlinear combination of t-distributions

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, computational-mathematics

Let $\varepsilon$ be distributed according to the following $t$-distribution:

$$p(\varepsilon) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu+1} 2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac \nu 2\right)[(\nu-2) \pi\sigma^2]^{1/2}}\left[1+\frac 1 {\nu-2}\left(\frac \varepsilon \sigma \right)^2\right]^{-\frac{\nu+1} 2}$$

so that $\operatorname{E}[\varepsilon]=0$ and $\operatorname{Var}[\varepsilon] = \sigma^2$. Consider the r.v. $\zeta = \frac \varepsilon \sigma$ which has unit variance.

Is it possible to compute in closed form
$\operatorname{E}\left[\frac{\zeta^2}{(a+\zeta^2)^2}\right],\quad a\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: How can it have unit variance if you let $\nu$ range over all possible values?

Comment: In this parametrization the variance of $\zeta$ is 1 whatever the value of $\nu$ is.